# Как сделать скролл в блоке?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как установить скролл внутри блока? Использую Bootstrap.
Пробовал так, но это не сработало.

```
.div {
  background-color: #e2e5e8;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для полноты реализации лучше использовать overflow для x,y:

```
.div {
      background-color: #e2e5e8;
      max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

или для постоянного скрола

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в css прописать "overflow: scroll",также добавить необходимую ширину и высоту блоку.